# Oracle Database: how to restrict a user to see only his/her own data?

Tags: database, plsql, oracle11g

For example I have a table like this:

```
                 +-----------------------------+
                 |        sample_table         |
                 +-----------------------------+
                 |  col_1  |  col_2  |  col_3  |
                 +-----------------------------+
User_1 Entered : |'val_1_1'|'val_1_2'|'val_1_3'|
                 +-----------------------------+
User_2 Entered : |'val_2_1'|'val_2_2'|'val_2_3'|
                 +-----------------------------+
```

now I want if each above users issue below query:

```
Select * from sample_table
```

the result
for **`User_1`** be:

```
+-----------------------------+
|  col_1  |  col_2  |  col_3  |
+-----------------------------+
|'val_1_1'|'val_1_2'|'val_1_3'|
+-----------------------------+
```

and for **`User_2`** be:

```
+-----------------------------+
|  col_1  |  col_2  |  col_3  |
+-----------------------------+
|'val_2_1'|'val_2_2'|'val_2_3'|
+-----------------------------+
```

what is a good way to restrict each user to access (select-update-delete) only to his/her data? (all users can do inserting data but I have them to be only view or modify their data). Thanks for your answer and guides.
***Note:*** I mean **`Database users`** but It would be appreciated if anyone give a solution for **`application users`** too.

Comment: You need to be specific whether it is an `application` user or a `database` user?

Comment: Hello @LalitKumarB, I meant 'database' user but if I want to know the best way for 'application' user too, I'll edit the post now

Comment: Unless you store the user that entered the data in the table there is no way you can later filter it out. So you have to add an "owner" column to the table

Comment: Check Oracle feature: [Virtual Private Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm). However that also requires your data contains which user entered the data as pointed out by @a_horse_with_no_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Data_Owner field to the table populated by the USER function. Don't allow direct access to the table. All access is through a view that exposes only those rows matching the USER value of whoever queries the view. An "instead of" trigger on the view can use the USER function to control the DML.

```
create view Sample as
select col_1, col_2, col3
from   Sample_Table
where  Data_Owner = USER;
```

For app users, instead of USER just use a UDF which supplies the app username or USER if there isn't one. The details of that will, of course, depend on how you maintain the app usernames.

Comment: Thanks for this Idea, I've seen this mechanism before but didn't review it and haven't payed attention to it, anyway thank you for your answer.